# Required field in model

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Before I was using Python NDB API and there was `required` attribute which I can set on properties. I can't find anything similar in Objectify documentation. How to do that with Objectify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the standard java bean validation framework for this:

http://beanvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that objectify has [no such functionality](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/AnnotationReference), where you would require user to set a value of field.

You can however prevent saving of fields with null value: `@IgnoreSave(IfNull.class)`. (you can use any of the [`If][2]` subclasses: `IfDefault, IfEmpty, IfEmptyString, IfFalse`, etc..)

Comment: I just understand that I can make no-arg constructor private (because it is required by objectify) and make one more public constructor with all required field values. But `@IgnoreSave(IfNull.class)` sure is helpful, I've don't even thought about it, thanks.